# Converting some get and set code from C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I have my small framework wrote in C# and SeleniumWebDriver and now I want to learn Java. I try to create new framework in Java according to my C# framework and I have problem with some code related with get and set because in Java that not exist.

In Java I tried to rewrite this but without any success and I haven't got already any idea.

This is my C# code which i need to write in Java:

```
 private static IWebDriver _driver;

 public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if (_driver == null)
                {
                    InitializeDriver();
                }

                return _driver;
            }
            private set => _driver = value;
        }
```

It is possible to write this C# code in Java? 
Correction. Could somebody show me how to do it?
Thanks a lot for respond.

---

Comment: Side note : I would not call it refactoring but "Porting" or "Converting". But the answer is - it is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
private static IWebDriver driver;

public static void SetDriver(IWebDriver Driver) {
    driver = Driver;
}

public static IWebDriver GetDriver() {
    return driver;
}
```

this is Eclipse Getter/Setter Generated form.

you can also use generate getter and setters function in Eclipse menu

[Source > Generate Getter and Setters ]

Comment: Isn't the default naming convention for methods in java to use camelCase? If so, why does eclipse use PascalCase?

Comment: @Joelius sorry, I put code manually. this is my pattern to code.default is camelCase as you told.